# How to externalize applicationContext and construct the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext object

Tags: java, spring, spring-context

I need to externalize by spring applicationContext configuration.
I run my jar as :

```
java -jar myjar.jar --spring.config.location=file:///Users/nsarkar/temp/config/applicationContext.xml
```

How would spring understand this property and what do i have to set the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext constructor with?

Does spring know the location automatically since the names are predefined by spring? OR do we have to still pass the parameters taking from command line argument?

The following code isnt working.

```
public class RestaurantPromoCooking {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classPathXmlApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
    CookFood cookFood = classPathXmlApplicationContext.getBean("promoItem", CookFood.class);
    cookFood.cookItem();
}
```

}

I need to externalize my config. Over the internet, all the suggestions were till using the property while running the jar and not beyond that.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What part _specifically_ of the configuration do you need externalized?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- : Entire application context, specifically bean specifications needs to be externalised

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom property like this

`java -DmyContextLocation=/home/myuser/context.xml -jar myjar.jar`

And then in the code do the following:

```
FileSystemXmlApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("file:" + System.getProperty("myContextLocation");
```

Comment: This is fine, but i need to understand the spring variable spring.config.location and its USAGE.

Comment: @Nilotpal from what I googled looks like that property works only in spring boot